# What is a more ressource using way to select basing on a variables value?

Tags: php

Hello Stackoverflow community,

i whonder if there is an less ressource using way to select an action based on a variables value than having multiple if-clauses. I think there was something like

```
select $variable
case value1 {some code}
case value2 {other code}
```

but is it more lightweight than several if clauses ?

Thanks in advance,
spechter

Comment: i think you want a switch: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php but it is really  NOT a resource issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, php, like many C-flavored languages, has the [switch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement to avoid using many if statements:

```php
switch($testVar) {
    case 1:
        handleOne();
        break;
    case 2:
        handleTwo();
        break;
    case 3:
        handleThree();
        break;
    default:
        handleOther();
}
```

Comment: works fine for me and doesn't seem to block the old system i'm using as server right now. thank you :)